# YA wizard novel about an orphan who becomes a witch and ultimately sacrifices herself to achieve something

Tags: story-identification, novel, wizards

I’m having trouble remembering what a certain book was called and I’d really love some help. It was the last of a trilogy (I read the last book first because they’re not related, really).

It’s about an orphan girl who’s roughly 14 years old and has been raised by a sect of wizards who wear purple robes. The two main relevant characters other than the girl are her male best friend who is the same age as her, and the girl’s mentor/man who raised her, who is a wizard in his late 30s-40s. The girl’s parents are unknown, though if I remember correctly she knows her mother came to the wizards pregnant and then died during childbirth.

The girl eventually harnesses her powers as a witch. I can’t remember the conflict but I know we find out that the girl is actually the daughter of an evil wizard who had been the villain of the previous book, and that her mother was still alive, albeit in a comatose-like state as punishment for the evil deeds she had done as the wizard’s wife. At the end of the book, the girl sacrifices herself for something (can’t remember) and then instead of dying, wakes up a few years later...without having aged at all.

I know this isn’t much to go on, but I know the plotlines of the previous books I looked them up after I read the last one. The first book is essentially the origin story of the evil wizard, the orphan girl’s father. The second book takes place years later and is the story of the girl’s mentor as a young man. I read the last book around 2007-2010, so it wasn’t written after that. I think they were written in the late 90s or early 2000s.

Comment: This is probably not what you’re thinking of, but this vaguely reminds me of the Septimus Heap series.